# What's the best way to use a for-loop in an if/else statement that performs a similar task?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, foreach

In the code below, even if the if/else statement evaluates to true or false, the `doSomething()` function is being called. What I was wondering is if there is a way to refactor this code to make it "DRYer." In my actual code, the body of the loop is longer than just a single function being called, so I figure it's worth refactoring.

```js
if (somethingIsTrue) {
    array1.forEach(val => {
        doSomething(val);
    });
} else {
    array2.forEach(val => {
        doSomething(val);
    });
}
```

Comment: As the answers have pointed out, this is rather trivial to solve, but that is because your example is simple, and the ONLY difference is which array is being operated on. Is your actual code that way too, that the ONLY difference which object is being operated on? I can't believe that is it, because gain it's trivial. Please provide more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional operator can be used here. There's probably no need for the anonymous function wrapper either.

```
(somethingIsTrue ? array1 : array2).forEach(doSomething);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would isolate the logic into a common function and pass the array to it. The function doesn't need to know which array its iterating over and that logic of deciding which array can be handled outside the function.

```js
let somethingIsTrue = true;
const mArr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const mArr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

businessLogic(somethingIsTrue ? mArr1 : mArr2);
somethingIsTrue = !somethingIsTrue;
console.log('---------------------------');
businessLogic(somethingIsTrue ? mArr1 : mArr2);

function businessLogic(mArr) {
  mArr.forEach(val => console.log(val));
}
```